# How to workaround a memory leak in Oracle

Tags: oracle, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have jobs in Oracle that can run for hours doing a lot of calculations involving (but not limited to) XmlTransform. I have noticed that the PGA memory is increasing (and the performance degrading) gradually until at some point the job fails with an out of memory (PGA) message. We have applied some fixes, but they don't seem to solve the issue.
Stopping the jobs and restarting them, solves my issue, the performance is good again and the memory is low...
All the code is written in PL/SQL and SQL.

Question:
As I want to solve this as soon as possible, I was wondering how I can workaround this type of issue in Oracle.

My main thinking goes to somehow:

- restarting the job after some time (possibly the most simple solution) using Advanced Queuing
- restart the current session?
- executing some code syncronously in another session, maybe another job.

Oracle 12.1.0.2

EDIT: As asked here's sample code with XMLTransform:

```
function i_Convert_Xml_To_Clob (p_Zoek_Result_Type_Id in Zoek_Result_Type.Zoek_Result_Type_Id%type,
                                p_Xml                 in xmltype,
                                p_Xml_Transformation  in xmltype) return clob is
  mResult clob;
begin
  if p_Xml_Transformation is not null then
    select Xmltransform (p_Xml, p_Xml_Transformation).getclobval()
      into mResult
    from Dual;
  elsif p_Xml is not null then
    mResult := p_Xml.getclobval();
  else
    mResult := null;
  end if;

  return mResult;
end i_Convert_Xml_To_Clob;
```

Comment: why call it a memory leak? you need to tune-fix your job to be more efficient, or give the database more memory so it can do the work you're asking it to do

Comment: @thatjeffsmith as mentioned, the memory usage is increasing, but it shouldn't be. I fine tuned the code a lot, but could not find a possible source for the increase. I can somehow restart the jobs, but that is easier said than done.

Comment: yeah, but we can't help you - you need to show us your code, your traces, show us why the memory is increasing and why you think it shouldn't be

Comment: @thatjeffsmith thanks for the help, but I'm asking a general method to somehow restart or reset the session, or to use a deposable session to solve this issue.

Comment: restarting the job won't fix it, if the problem is with the job, it will just 'leak memory' again, as you say

Comment: anyways, i'd suggest debugging your job. is your calculation being done via sql or plsql? look at an explain plan or dbms_profiler run of that code

Comment: Could we chat about this? I don't know how to start it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132515/discussion-between-thatjeffsmith-and-rvheddeg).

Answer (score 2):

Can you or a DBA  monitor temp lob usage from another session using V$TEMPORARY_LOBS. If the number of lobs is increasing then the session is not freeing them correctly and this will lead increasing PGA usage (Note this is not a leak).

The most common scenario is when processing a statement that returns one or more temporary lobs, for instance XMLTRANSMFORM().getClobVal().

It is not uncommon for (Java ?) developers to forget that a TEMP LOB is a SESSION level object and the resources assoicated with it will not be freed as a result of the client handle or reference going out of scope. Eg If you get a TEMP lob into a JAVA Clob object you can not rely on garbage collection to clean up the LOB. You must explicitly free the lob before overwriting it with the next lob or the LOB resources will be held by the server until the session ends.

Since we don't have sample code we cannot definitely state this is what is happening in your case.

Comment: All my code is written in PL/SQL and SQL. Does your explanation still hold then? I will try to free the lob after the xmltransform though.

Comment: It depends, a pure PL/SQL procedure that is not returning the output of the transform (eg is storing it in the database) _should_ not need to worry about freeing the Temp lob, but it's still good practice. The minute any of the LOBs that are generated in the PL/SQL are handed off to a client the LOBS become session level objects and need to be freed.

Comment: Again we'd really need to see the code and any associated client code to be sure. If it is a pure PL/SQL solution you should be able to queryt V$TEMPORARY_LOBS from the PL/SQL block and output the number of LOBS using DBMS_OUTPUT.

Comment: I added some sample code. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: The temporary clob mResult is being returned by the function. What code is invoking the function. If this code is running on a client (eg you invoking i_Convert_Xml_To_Clob  via JDBC or OCI then you must free the temporary clob when you have finished processing it.

Comment: Everything is PL/SQL. It is all run inside a job.

Comment: I just checked this job again. The V$TEMPORARY_LOBS keeps practically the same during the calculation. No meaningfull changes detected.